# Multiple Models in View by ViewModel

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am beginner in ASP.NET MVC and trying to add multiple models in view by using `ViewModel.cs` but I can't get it in my view `Index.cshtml` anyone can guide me how can I get it?

**ViewModel.cs**

```
public class ViewModel
    {
        public IEnumerable<ContactLens.Models.manufacturer> manufacturer {get; set;}
        public IEnumerable<ContactLens.Models.brand> brand { get; set; }
    }
```

**HomeController.cs**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private Entities db = new Entities();

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Welcome to my demo!";
            ViewModel mymodel = new ViewModel();
            mymodel.manufacturer = db.manufacturers.ToList();
            mymodel.brand = db.brands.ToList();
            return View(mymodel);
        }
     }
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
@model ViewModel        
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
     --------
<h3 class="menu_head">Top Manufacturers</h3>
 <ul class="menu">
        @foreach (var manufacturer in Model)
        {
           <li class="item1">
           <a href="#"><img class="arrow-img" src="images/f_menu.png" alt="" /> @manufacturer.man_name </a>
           </li>
        }
</ul>
 <h3 class="menu_head">Top Brands</h3>
  <ul class="menu">
         @foreach (var brand in Model)
         {
           <li class="item1">
           <a href="#"><img class="arrow-img" src="images/f_menu.png" alt="" /> @brand.brand_name </a>
           </li>
         }
</ul>
  -------
```

It is showing me an error at `@model ViewModel`due to it, I can't access models in `Index.cshtml`.

Comment: Try using `@foreach (var manufacturer in Model.manufacturer)` & `@foreach (var brand in Model.brand)`. Similar construction: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ff2f08/multiple-models-in-single-view-in-mvc/.

Comment: waoooo... its working. Thank you @TetsuyaYamamoto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should be

```
@model [Full Path of Your Model]
```

So in your case it might be:

```
@model [SolutionName].[ModelDirectoryIfAny].[Model]
```

**Edit**

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
     --------
<h3 class="menu_head">Top Manufacturers</h3>
 <ul class="menu">
        @foreach (var manufacturer in Model.manufacturer)
        {

        }
</ul>
 <h3 class="menu_head">Top Brands</h3>
  <ul class="menu">
         @foreach (var brand in Model.brand)
         {

         }
</ul>
```

Comment: I have this file in Models folder but it is not accepting **@model Moldels.ViewModel**

Comment: @NabiaSaroosh please check my update, Your solution name must come first then Models before ViewModel. Something like this `@model SolutionName.Models.ViewModel`

Comment: please guide me how can I get _SolutionName_ in my case?

Comment: @NabiaSaroosh tht is the name of you project or solution

Comment: Ok, got it. Thank you, but  now it is showing me error at **@foreach (var brand in Model)** this line.

Comment: check my updates, should be `Model.manufacturer` for manufacturers and `Model.brand` for the brands

Comment: Thank You @jamiedanq i got my solution.

Comment: please see my below answer.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my issue by replacing just `@model ViewModel` into

`@model [SolutionName].[ModelDirectoryIfAny].[Model]`

and

```
  // some code
@foreach (var manufacturer in Model)
 // some code

@foreach (var brand in Model)
```

into

```
  // some code
@foreach (var manufacturer in Model.manufacturer)
 // some code
@foreach (var brand in Model.brand)
```

respectively in **Index.cshtml**